# Trying to find Dominant Eigenvalue via MATLAB, running into Indexing Error

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

Here is my code:

```
A = [1 2 4 8 16; 2 2 0 0 0; 4 0 4 0 0; 8 0 0 8 0; 16 0 0 0 16]; %here is our problem matrix
b = [1;1;1;1;1]; %intial guess vector
n = 100; %number of iterations
tol = 0.001; %tolerance - problem stats two decimal places to right
b0 = b;
for count = 1:n
    b = A*b0;
    M = max(b)
    b = b/M;
    if abs(b-b0)<tol
        break
    end
    b0 = b;
    fprintf('Iteration #:',count)
    fprintf('Eigenvalue is:',b)
end
```

Running into this error:

Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 1.

Error in test (line 8)
M = max(b)

Up until that point my code works as intended. I cannot seem to figure out the issue here.

Thank you!

I was expecting to get iterations to fit within the iterations and tolerance with the dominant eigenvalue.

Comment: Did you define a variable with the name `max`? That would hide the function. You should never use standard function names for your variables. Do `clear max`.

Comment: Cris got it I think. If you get such error in future, you can always check what is `max` by using `which max`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Strangely enough, I tried in an older version of MATLAB and it worked totally normal. Super strange!